# Insert query fail in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I don't know why but the insert query fail, this is my code:

```
public function insert_resource($resource) 
{
    try
    {
        $data = array(
            'descrizione' => $resource['descrizione'],
            'sigla' => $resource['sigla'],
            'colore' => $resource['colore'],
            'planning' => $resource['planning'],
            'data' => 0
        );

        if(!$this->db->insert('risorse', $data))
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't insert the resource");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now the `$resource` contains all data like:

- descrizione
- sigla
- colore
- planning
- data

  except for the id, that's `auto_increment` so I doesn't include the id in the `$data` variable.
  In the network tab I get:

> Can't insert the resource
>
> id: null
>
> status: "SUCCESS"

why happean this?

**LAST_QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO `risorse` (`descrizione`, `sigla`, `colore`, `planning`, `data`, `id`) VALUES ('sdfdf', 'fdfd', '12FFEF', 'NoviSoft', 0, 'null')
```

Comment: Have your `id` field is also set to `not null` ??

Comment: No I don't pass the id, I should be?

Comment: I mean have your id in phpmyadmin is `auto increment and not null` ??

Comment: `$this->db->last_query()` use this you check your query

Comment: Check my update to see what the metod return

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96349/discussion-between-dillinger-and-saty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->db->insert('risorse', $data);
if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == 0 ){ 
     echo $this->db->_error_message();
     throw new Exception("Can't insert the resource");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've found the problem, I wrong a column name in the data, you help me a lot, thank you. Have a good day :)